# Use Wordpress Inside Laravel Nginx

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx

I'm trying to have Wordpress installed in other folder than "/public" on Laravel project.

The laravel path:
/home/forge/domain.com/

Wordpress path:
/home/forge/blog.domain.com/

But I want to use this url and not as subdomain:
domain.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

You can use a location section in your nginx configuration file:

```
location ^blog/ {
    root /home/forge/blog.example.com;

    //your regular nginx configuration
}
```

You may also use a reverse proxy. This means you have to put the blog on a different URL (like blog.domain.com) and then point blog/ to that URL. For example:

```
location ^blog/ {
    sub_filter_types *;
            sub_filter_once off;
            sub_filter 'blog.example.com' 'www.example.com/blog';

            proxy_pass http://blog.example.com/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_redirect http://blog.example.com http://www.example.com;
}
```

The subfilter rewrites all URLs in your html output. The proxy_redirect makes sure cookies and headers are corrected as well.